# HTML5 + JavaScript - Mouse Positioning

Tags: html, position, mouse

I'm fairly new to HTML5, but I'm learning, and for now - I'm working on a really simple game.

What I'm trying to do is get the mouse X and Y position related to the canvas, and have an image to follow the mouse (like a crosshair, to aim).

But for now, I just want to pull the mouse values.

So, I have a function called init, which initialises everything. It's called when an image sprite is loaded:

```
function init(){
    drawBg();
    startDrawing();

    document.addEventListener('keydown', checkKeyDown, false);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', checkKeyUp, false);

    document.addEventListener('ommousemove', mouseTarget, false);

}
```

I'm not 100% if the 'ommousemove' is correct, not sure what I'm suppose to put their. I then have the mouseTarget function:

```
function mouseTarget(e){

    var mouseX;
    var mouseY;

    if(e.offsetX){
        mouseX = e.offsetX;
        mouseY = e.offsetY;
    }
    else if(e.layerX){
        mouseX = e.layerX;
        mouseY = e.layerY;
    }

    console.debug("Mouse X: " +  mouseX + " Mouse Y: " + mouseY);

}
```

I also have a function called 'draw', which is called every 5 frames (every update), so I'm assuming I need to check the mouse position within that?

```
function draw(){
   mouseTarget();
}
```

But then I get an error: Uncaught: TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetX' of undefined.
What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Just a note. That's a JavaScript API, it has no real connection with the HTML5 specification (which is *strictly* for HTML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (as you suspected) is with this line

```
document.addEventListener('ommousemove', mouseTarget, false);
```

It should be

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseTarget, false);
```

The `e` parameter in the `mouseTarget` function will only contain the event information when called via an event. In your case it is never being called via an event, but only via the `draw` function.

That is why you are getting the `Cannot read property 'offsetX' of undefined.` error, as in reality you are trying to access `undefined.offsetX`

What you should do is keep a the mouse position in separate variables and then just reference them in the 'draw' function.